# Script can't parse title from a redirected url

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I've written a script in python with selenium to get the header address from a webpage. The url I used within my script gets redirected automatically within seconds. This is where my script encounters an error. I'm pasting a portion of that error to give you an idea.

```
ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
```

[Link to that url which gets redirected to another page](https://www.rightmove.co.uk/propertyMedia/redirect.html?propertyId=30578943&contentId=1625965454&index=1)

Script I've tried with:

```
from contextlib import closing
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support import ui

url = "https://www.rightmove.co.uk/propertyMedia/redirect.html?propertyId=30578943&contentId=1625965454&index=1"

with closing(webdriver.Chrome()) as wd:
    wait = ui.WebDriverWait(wd, 10)
    wd.get(url)
    item = wait.until(lambda driver: driver.find_element_by_css_selector("h1.header_address__title")).text
    print(item)
```

This is the output I would like to have from that page:

```
Park View Back Road, Locharbriggs, Dumfries, DG1
```

This is what I see before that error:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might need to replace

```
item = wait.until(lambda driver: driver.find_element_by_css_selector("h1.header_address__title")).text
```

that means *wait for specific element to appear in DOM and immediately get its currently visible text (might return empty string)*

with

```
item = wait.until(lambda driver: driver.find_element_by_css_selector("h1.header_address__title").text)
```

that means *wait for specific element and return its visible text once it's NOT AN EMPTY STRING*

But IMHO you can simply do

```
item = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("h1.header_address__title").get_attribute('textContent')
```

to get the text value even if that text is currently not displayed on page

As for your `chromedriver that stops working` issue: try to update both [Chrome](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95414?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en) and [chromedriver](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.43/) to last versions

Comment: Now it gives me a very friendly exception error @sir Andersson. Your suggestion to update the chromedriver relieved me from that vicious problem (the one you see in the above image). The error I'm having now  for first ` `selector` is `raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: `. For second suggestion : `    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"h1.header_address__title"}`

Comment: @asmitu , oh... sorry :) I didn't check element - just used you selector... let me check it now

Comment: @asmitu , yep. Some remarks :) The first one is not working because it seem that when browser window is not maximized, the header is not visible, so rather use `wd.maximize_window()` in the beginning of script or `item = wait.until(lambda driver: driver.find_element_by_css_selector("h1.header_address__title").get_attribute('textContent'))` (`driver.find_element_by_css_selector("h1.header_address__title").get_attribute('textContent')` without wait is not working because it's not found as initial page is not our target page)

Comment: Btw, before updating my chromedriver I was having success with other sites but encountered the above error with this site. Was there any reason for this mysterious behaviour? Feel free to ignore if you don't like to answer this portion. Thanks again sir.

Comment: @asmitu , I didn't make any researches actually, so I don't know why this happens. I just know that in case of any OS errors the first thing to do is to check browser-webDriver compatibility :)